# Is it normal to get a Gateway Timeout after deploying a new release to Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, episerver

I have an Episerver website developed in .NET. The web app is hosted as an **Azure Web App**.

The application works well, but every time I deploy from **Dev** environment to **Staging** (pre-production), and/or to **Production**, I get a `Gateway Timeout` for about 4 minutes.

I'd just like to know if this is normal, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: In which environment is this? Sounds like a DXC setup? If so, you should have a deployment slot for production at least, enabling go-live without downtime. If an environment is simply restarted (because of deploy or oterhwise) you'll most likely get a gateway timeout for a short while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you swap an application into production, please ensure the staging slot is warmed up before being swapped into production. This eliminates downtime when you deploy your web app. After the swap, the traffic redirection is seamless. If you encounter gateway timeout, I would suggest you use [dig web interface](https://www.digwebinterface.com/) to look further into this issue.